# How do I validate a unique transaction id in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, validation, java-8, transactions

Context :-

I'm validating my rest apis in spring boot. There's a transaction id that is being sent in every API call. I'm writing a custom annotation to ensure that the transaction id that is sent every time is unique. Here's an example of the request api body :-

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-05-12T04:15:28.318Z",
  "txnid": "acscscs-4a18-11e8-96ff-05sdsadd",
  "cust_id": "abc@gmail.com"
}
```

How do I ensure that the `txnid` transaction id is not repeated i.e. if I use the same transaction id twice then there should be an error thrown?

I was planning to save each transaction id to customer id map in a table, query the table to check if the transaction id is unique. Is this an efficient method?

Or is there any other efficient/simpler method to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

You solution is fine, but the downside is database might not be the source of truth for `txnid`. Lets say `txnid` is present is saved in api but saving in database failed.
I would suggest the following solution:

*Query the api for `txnid` on the fly (assumption: an api to provide the response `HTTP.OK 200` if the `txnid` is present or else `HTTP.NOT_FOUND` 400). The api will be the only source of truth in this case.*

Comment: I don't have an API currently for this. My question is how do I ensure that the same transaction id cannot be used in subsequent requests?